# reading excel dataframe starting from specific location based on the cell value

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following Excel file:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 |
| 2 | 22 | start |
| 3 | 33 | 333 |
| 4 | 44 | 444 |

I want to read the file in a dataframe making sure that I start to read it above the row where the Start value is. I tried the following:

```
df=df[(df.iloc[:, 2] == "start").shift(-1,fill_value=False).cummax()]
```

However, not only the row where start is located changes but also the col between the sheet in the workbook. Is there a way where I can look up the value I need to start with by using the col and row location?

that is what I want to have:

| C |
| --- |
| 111 |
| start |
| 333 |
| 444 |

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using 'skiprows' ? Try: df = pd.read_excel(file_name, skiprows=1)

Comment: this won't work as the the row also changes between the sheets in the dataframe

Comment: So in your example above, you only want the rows where A is 2, 3 and 4 right?

Comment: I am trying to start reading that data from the col and row where start located. Will update the questions in a sec

Comment: @Kimchi - See if the answer below works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#index of first row above "start"
row_index = df[df.shift(-1).eq("start").any(axis=1)].index.min()

#name of first column before the column that contains "start"
col_index = df.loc[:,df.shift(-1, axis=1).eq("start").any(0)].columns[0]

#select all rows and columns per the above indices.
>>> df.loc[row_index:, col_index:]

    B      C
0  11    111
1  22  start
2  33    333
3  44    444
```

Comment: this works! can I use the following to read also from the col before the start col: 
col_index = df.loc[:,df.shift(-1).eq("start").any(0)].columns[0]

Comment: See the edit! That should give you what you want

Comment: is there a good material I can use to familiarize myself with how to make similar queries?